# Delete a leading space

Tags: mysql, sql

In my MySQL database I'm looking to remove a leading space in a column, it's completely destroying my export on excel with that...
[column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HkcA.jpg)

I've tried this command :

```
Update test set question = ltrim(rtrim(question));
```

But it didn't change anything...

Comment: I guess the issue is in the column name? For that you need to use 'ALTER TABLE tablename " statement with the column rename clause, google it for your database type

Comment: Try `select * from test where question != ltrim(rtrim(question))`. Anything returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have a CR, try to remove it:

```
Update test set question = replace(replace(question,'\n',''),'\r','');
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be because of trailing new lines, you can remove those extra new lines using below query

```
UPDATE test SET question = TRIM(TRAILING '\n' FROM 'question')
```